# Is it possible to find the screen resolution from within a C program under Linux?

Tags: c, linux, screen, screen-resolution

I know I can get the screen resolution from the command line on Linux using xdpyinfo but is it also possible to do this from within a C program? If so how?

Comment: Of course it's possible, OS's are written in C. Look up the relevant documentation for your system, there is nothing in standard C to help.

Comment: Of course, how do you think `xdpyinfo` gets the info? This is the source code it, you can see how it does: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xdpyinfo/tree/xdpyinfo.c. But I warn you, bare X11 lib is not easy to use.

Comment: @DeiDei Of course standard C does not address this. That is not what I am asking. And I am looking for a general Linux solution not just one for my system. If you know of any relevant documentation please post the information.

Comment: The general solution would be using the libX11 or a wrapper of libX11 like GTK+ or Qt. They might have wrappers of these functions to get this information much easier. But look at the code of xdpyinfo, it's not that long  and not to complicated to understand.

Comment: I think you might want to link with and use the Xrandr library. The command line utility is 'xrandr -q'

Comment: @DavidS - *"Of course standard C does not address this. That is not what I am asking."* - but your titular question asks if it is possible, and the replies say it is platform specific ...

Comment: Please be more specific which "screen" you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Pablo's advice (thanks Pablo!) I was able to hack xdpyinfo.c to get what I want. Demo code is:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <X11/Xwindows.h>
#endif

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void
print_screen_info(Display *dpy, int scr)
{
    /*
     * there are 2.54 centimeters to an inch; so there are 25.4 millimeters.
     *
     *     dpi = N pixels / (M millimeters / (25.4 millimeters / 1 inch))
     *         = N pixels / (M inch / 25.4)
     *         = N * 25.4 pixels / M inch
     */

    double xres, yres;

    xres = ((((double) DisplayWidth(dpy,scr)) * 25.4) /
            ((double) DisplayWidthMM(dpy,scr)));
    yres = ((((double) DisplayHeight(dpy,scr)) * 25.4) /
            ((double) DisplayHeightMM(dpy,scr)));

    printf ("\n");
    printf ("screen #%d:\n", scr);
    printf ("  dimensions:    %dx%d pixels (%dx%d millimeters)\n",
            XDisplayWidth (dpy, scr),  XDisplayHeight (dpy, scr),
            XDisplayWidthMM(dpy, scr), XDisplayHeightMM (dpy, scr));
    printf ("  resolution:    %dx%d dots per inch\n",
            (int) (xres + 0.5), (int) (yres + 0.5));
}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display *dpy;                        /* X connection */
    char *displayname = NULL;            /* server to contact */
    int i;                      

    dpy = XOpenDisplay (displayname);
    if (!dpy) {
        fprintf (stderr, "unable to open display \"%s\".\n",
                 XDisplayName (displayname));
        exit (1);
    }

    printf ("name of display:    %s\n", DisplayString (dpy));
    printf ("default screen number:    %d\n", DefaultScreen (dpy));
    printf ("number of screens:    %d\n", ScreenCount (dpy));

    for (i = 0; i < ScreenCount (dpy); i++) {
        print_screen_info (dpy, i);
    }

    XCloseDisplay (dpy);
    exit (0);
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc test.c -lX11
```

Output looks like:

```
erpsim1:~/linux_lib/test> ./a.out 
name of display:    localhost:15.0
default screen number:    0
number of screens:    1

screen #0:
  dimensions:    4400x1400 pixels (1552x494 millimeters)
  resolution:    72x72 dots per inch
```

Answer (score 1):

If `xdpyinfo` works for you, just use that.  Create some pipes, `fork()`, connect the pipes, and `exec(xdpyinfo)`  It's a gazillion times easier than figuring out libX11; someone's already done that work for you.  This isn't the idiom I'd use, but it gets the idea across:

```
int filedes[2];
if (pipe(filedes) == -1) {
  perror("pipe");
  exit(1);
}

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
  perror("fork");
  exit(1);
} else if (pid == 0) {
  while ((dup2(filedes[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) {}
  close(filedes[1]);
  close(filedes[0]);
  execl(cmdpath, cmdname, (char*)0);
  perror("execl");
  _exit(1);
}
close(filedes[1]);
```

The `while(...EINTR))` loop is just about guarding against interrupts during the file descriptor close and duplication.